Interfacing S11108 image sensor
We are working on a project involving the S11108 image sensor. We aim to reconstruct an image the sensor captures, which is connected to an Arduino.  Unfortunately, we haven’t been able to find adequate resources online regarding using this sensor or coding for image reconstruction.
Could anyone provide us with:

Example code or references that can help us process data from the
sensor and reconstruct images.
Resources or tutorials that
explain the process of image reconstruction.
Your support would
be greatly appreciated, as we are eager to understand and make
progress on this project!


Could you link us to any material on the S11108? Even just a product brief or a basic datasheet? If there's nothing, then you simply can't use that sensor and have to find a different one.

You would need an Arduino, that contains a very fast ADC providing 1 Mega samples per second and a feature to start a conversion by a dedicated hardware input. I am not aware of one with this capabilities, at least not if using standard libraries.
